# Syntax error bitwise operations c

Tags: c++, syntax, operators, bit-manipulation

I can't figure out how to solve this error: [Error] expected ')' before '<<' token

This code is inside a macro:

```
    #define SUM_VARS(a, b, c, d)                               \
    unsigned int *inta = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&a); \
    unsigned int *intb = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&b); \
    unsigned int *intc = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&c); \
    unsigned int *intd = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&d); \

    (((*inta << 24) & 0xFF000000) | ((*intb << 16) & 0x00FF0000) | ((*intc << 8)  & 0x0000FF00) | (*intd & 0xFF))
```

I really don't get where the error could be... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Resolve the macro by hand and you will see. Why not use a function anyway?

Comment: Added C++ tag - preprocessor macros, templates (especially reinterpret_cast) - should be in your sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my - this is not save at all...

Imagine you call this with `SUM_VARS(12, ...)` - 12 is a constant, does not have a memory address, and thus your macro fails at `&12`.

Call it with `SUM_VARS(n + 7, ...)`. You get then – omitting the cast – `unsigned int* inta = &n + 7;`. As n is not an array, undefined behaviour! Even if it was not, you are getting a pointer to a value completely unrelated to n...

Call it with `SUM_VARS(c, ...)`, while c is of type `char` or `short` - you are then reading memory past the variable c (undefined behaviour). OK, on a little endian machine, you would be masking the unwanted parts away, on a big endian machine...

Why those pointers at all?

Why not simply

```
#define SUM_VARS(a, b, c, d) \
    ((a) << 24 & 0xff000000) \
    |                        \
    ((b) << 16 & 0x00ff0000) \
    |                        \
    ((c) << 16 & 0x0000ff00) \
    |                        \
    ((d) << 16 & 0x000000ff)
```

Notice the parentheses around a, b, c, d; they are *very* important to assure that expressions containing operators with lower precedence are evaluated completely before the bitshift is applied.

You will be much safer, though, if you use a function for this (Olaf recommended so already). Make it inline, if you want to save the overhead of a function call (compiler is not compelled to follow this recommendation, but with such a simple function, most likely will):

```
inline unsigned int sumVars(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c, unsigned int d)
{
    return
        (a << 24 & 0xff000000)
        |
        (b << 16 & 0x00ff0000)
        |
        (c << 16 & 0x0000ff00)
        |
        (d << 16 & 0x000000ff);
}
```

Notice that you do not need the inner parentheses any more as now, the expressions are evaluated before the function call.

If you want to go on further, you could extend this to a template function:

```
template < typename T >
T sumAll(T t)
{
    return t;
}
template < typename T, typename ... Values >
T sumAll(T t, Values ... values)
{
    return t + sumAll(values...);
}
```